# SurveyMonkey API v3 creating a message, returns error: "The user does not have the required plan to make this request"

Tags: surveymonkey

I am using a wrapper library [SurveyMonkeyApiV3](https://github.com/chrislott/SurveyMonkeyApiV3) to connect to SurveyMonkey. While trying to create a new message with CreateCollectorMessage, which makes a POST to `https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/{0}/messages/` (where {0} is the collector id and the message contents are passed as parameters), I get the following error:

`The user does not have the required plan to make this request.`

The contents of the message are as simple as they can get:

```
CreateMessage createMsg = new CreateMessage()
{
    body_html = "[SurveyLink], [FooterLink] and [OptOutLink]",
    subject = "new survey",
    type = "invite",
    body_text = "[SurveyLink], [FooterLink] and [OptOutLink]",
    is_branding_enabled = false
};
```

This comes from a test that I run in the SurveyMonkeyApiV3 library itself.
The funny thing is that a month or so ago, the whole thing was working.
I tried with different accounts using different api keys and tokens, to no end.
All the accounts I use are free accounts.

The only thing that comes to mind is that maybe something changed in the API itself. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic users can access the endpoint you specified (`https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/{0}/messages/`) the issue is the key `is_branding_enabled` can only be disabled if you are a Platinum/Enterprise user.

Setting `is_branding_enabled` to true (or not including it, it is optional) should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried not including it, but that didn't work. So, I set it to true and my tests worked. Thanks.